# Call to a possibly undefined method checkCollisions through a reference with static type Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe, collision-detection

I know there are many questions answering something similar to this. However, this is *specifically* for Cory's collisiondetectionkit. I have installed it, and put the `com` folder in a random folder where I keep all my files. It looks like this:

[image]

This is the code which I have imported it with:

```
import com.coreyoneil.collision.*;
```

and this is where I call it in the code:

```
if(oCharUse == true){
    if(CollisionList.checkCollisions(b1, oChar) == true){
        trace("collision")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you should call the function on a CollisionList instance.

```
var collisionList:CollisionList = new CollisionList();

collisionList.addItem(oChar);
collisionList.addItem(b1);
...

var items:Array = collisionList.checkCollision();

if (items.length > 0)
{
   for each (var obj:Object in items)
   {
       var ret1:Boolean = obj.object1 == oChar  && obj.object2 == b1;
       var ret2:Boolean = obj.object2 == oChar  && obj.object1 == b1;

        if (ret1 || ret2)
        {
             //oChar and b1 has collision
        }
   }
}
```

Here is source code of [CollisionList](https://www.assembla.com/code/quickPool_2/subversion/nodes/com/coreyoneil/collision/CollisionList.as?rev=8)  and [CDK](https://www.assembla.com/code/quickPool_2/subversion/nodes/com/coreyoneil/collision/CDK.as?rev=8)

The main function is checkCollision of CollisionList and findCollisions of CDK, you may
see how it works.

Comment: Where would I put oChar & b1 in this case?